# How the keyword 'new' works especially when I initiate static nested class?

Tags: java, nested

```
public class NestedClassTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        OuterClass.NestedClass nestedObject = new OuterClass.NestedClass();
        nestedObject.printX();

        OuterClass outerObject = new OuterClass();
        //OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = new outerObject.InnerClass(); //Error!
        OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass();
        innerObject.printY();

        //OuterClass.NestedClass objectOfNested2 = outerObject.new NestedClass(); //Error!
    }
}

class OuterClass{
    static int x = 10;
    int y = 100;

    static class NestedClass{
        void printX(){
        System.out.println(x);
        }
    }

    class InnerClass{
        void printY(){
            System.out.println(y);
        }
    }
}
```

I was juggling with nested class and inner class. The difficult part was when I tried to initiate inner class with the keyword `new`.

I expected that `new outerObject.InnerClass()` would work just like 
`new OuterClass.NestedClass()` did. It didn't work but only `outerObject.new InnerClass()` worked. To me, keyword `new` coming after a variable(`outerObject` in my case) seemed very eerie and confusing. Why should it be this way? What is the logic behind this?

Moreover, `outerObject.new NestedClass()` didn't work, which meant more mysteries to me.

Please somebody help me understand how the keyword `new` works in detail.

Answer (score 1):

An instance of an inner class belongs to a specific instance of the outer class (that's what makes it different from a static nested class). You have to say `outerInstance.new InnerClass()` to tell Java which outer instance that is.

A static class, on the other hand, has no associated outer instance, and so you just specify the class name with `new` normally (in fact, you can import the nested class directly, and then you can just say `new NestedClass()`).